# Does Lucene back the API search now?

Tags: support, search

With the [announcement that Lucene is being used for site searches](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/) does it cover the API as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet.

It is a planned conversion, but we want all the bugs to shake out before switching the API over.